# How to ignore internal ReactJS code in the call stack while debugging ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

While I'm debugging code in ReactJS in Google DevTools (I've installed react devtools, by the way), a lot of layers in the call stack are from code from ReactJS itself, as opposed to code that I've written in the project I'm working on.

How can I hide those lines, so that I can focus on the parts of the call stack that involve my code?

I'm working on a website involving ReactJS, as opposed to a mobile device application.

[image: Example of a call stack with lots of lines involving ReactJS internal code]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can blackbox the React library files in DevTools. This stop the debugger from stepping into the code, and a message will appear in the call stack to say "x frames are hidden (black-boxed)".

See [Blackbox JavaScript Source Files](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#blackbox) for a complete guide on using this feature.

Comment: If you are finding this in 2020, the link you are looking for has changed: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#blackbox
(Now you can just right click on the script in the Sources panel and select "Blackbox" from the menu. Slick!)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can add script to ignore list